# No action perform when Window Frame closed in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, action

```
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent b) {

            // Do stuff
            if (socket != null) {

                    socket.close();
                    socket = null;

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    socket = null;
                }
                System.out.println("About to abort!");

            }
            dispose();

        }

    });
```

From the above code what I'm trying to achive is that when they click on the red X button it will check if the TCP socket is still connect or not, and if it still connecting then close(); and assign a null to the socket, and I want to print something, but nothing really happen at all.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: So the frame is disposed but nothing is printed, is that right? If so, that means that socket is null. No way to tell you why without seeing more code.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, but without even having that if statement there is nothing really printing?

Comment: @JBNizet nevermind I think it was my mistake about that the printing statement was inside the if statement! Sorry :S

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm sorry about that :( the TCP part is where I'm working with the upload method, but not from this one

Comment: OK I'm mollified.  Down vote removed.  Please take care with tags in future.

Comment: @AndrewThompson sure I will! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the close operation is set to `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```